# Assigning implementation of a generic interface to a property

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have an interface

```
public interface IStrategy<T> where T : BaseModel
{
    T GetModel(Guid userId);
}
```

and a concrete class inheriting the interface specifying that it should be a `ConcreteModel`

```
 public class ConcreteStrategy: IStrategy<ConcreteModel>
 {
     ConcreteModel GetModel(Guid userId) { ... }
 }
```

Now in the following method I can pass a new instance of `ConcreteStrategy` and everything works

```
 public class Manager
 {
    public TModel GetContentModel<TModel>(IStrategy<TModel> strategy, Guid userId)
        where TModel : ModelBase
    {
        return strategy.GetContentModel(userId);
    }
 }
```

But if I try to assign it to a property like this I get an error

```
public class Strategies
{
    public static IStrategy<ModelBase> MyStrategy { get; set; }
}

Strategies.MyStrategy = new ConcreteStrategy();
```

Is there a way I can achieve this in C# ?
I want to be able to make a factory method that encapsulates the logic for which strategy to use and just return an instance of some type of strategy class (like `ConcreteStrategy`).

The error I am getting is:

*Cannot implicitly convert type `IStrategy<ModelBase>` to `IStrategy<ConcreteModel>`*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make your interface [covariant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
public interface IStrategy<out T> where T : BaseModel
```

Note that it will work only if `T` only appears in an output position in the interface (which is the case in the code you have shown, but I don't know if it's your real code).